# Unable to access the windows partition

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I recently installed Linux Mint as dual boot along with the Windows 10. During installation I:

1. First shrank the 250GB harddisk to create 50GB space for the Linux
   Mint
2. I disabled secure boot in EUFI
3. Then I installed Linux Mint creating 3 partitions; one for filesystem, one for swap and one for
   /home directory.

Everything installed fine except that the Windows 10 partitions don't appear in the Explorer. `lsblk` shows that the windows partition is there but it is not mounted and it doesn't show any filesystem against it.

[image: windows partition not mounted]

I just disabled "Fast Boot" in power settings on Windows 10 and came back to Mint but still the same. Screenshot is attached. Any help how I could access the Windows data?

Comment: Try this: https://www.tecmint.com/mount-windows-partition-in-ubuntu/

Comment: There is nothing under /media. An devices don't show up under File Manager. So this article is no help

Comment: Try the **Disks** program (under *Settings*). My guess is that your main Windows 10 partition is nvme0n1p3, so mount that.

Comment: Do you have drivers for NTFS installed?

Comment: I didn't explicitly install them. Don't they come prepackaged with Mint?